# WCF Error "HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'"

Tags: wcf, ssl, credentials

Edit: I kinda forgot about this question! I ended up remapping the configuration, the error disappeared and I couldn't find the reason.

I have a WCF service that is hosted on IIS, and a Windows Forms client that is trying to connect to it.

The WCF service should be secured, so the IIS web app is configured to use a certificate that is issued by the domain (the CA is on the domain) issued to "localhost" for our dev environment.

The SSL settings on IIS is set to "Require SSL" and "Client certificates = Require".

The WCF service uses custom binding, and the configuration in the web.config is as follows:

```
  <diagnostics>
    <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" maxMessagesToLog="25" />
  </diagnostics>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="SpecificBehaviorType" name="MyCom.Service">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBindingConfiguration" contract="MyCom.IMyService">
        <!--<identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>-->
      </endpoint>
      <!--<host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8999/" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>-->
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="CustomBindingConfiguration">
        <MyComMessageEncoding innerMessageEncoding="textMessageEncoding" />

        <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="10000000" maxBufferPoolSize="10000000" requireClientCertificate="true" />


      </binding>
    </customBinding>

  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SpecificBehaviorType">
        <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

To enable the client to connect to the service, we exported the "localhost" certificate as "localhost.cer" file and used that file in our code (this should be another trusted certificate specific for the client, but we are using the localhost one for testing purposes). 
The client configuration is done programmatically (no specific reason why here according to my knowledge).

The client code is as following:

```
 Dim isHttps As Boolean = uri.ToLower().StartsWith("https")
        'TODO: set quotas for message size
        Dim binding As New CustomBinding()
        binding.Elements.Add(New MyComEncodingBindingElement(New TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap12, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)))
        'TODO: make configurable to support both http and https
        If isHttps Then
            Dim httpsBinding As New HttpsTransportBindingElement

            binding.Elements.Add(httpsBinding)
        Else
            Dim transport As New HttpTransportBindingElement()
            binding.Elements.Add(transport)
        End If

        Dim channelFactory = New ChannelFactory(Of IRequestChannel)(binding, New EndpointAddress(uri))

        channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Add(New MustUnderstandBehavior(False))

        If isHttps Then
            For counter As Integer = 0 To channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors.Count - 1
                If TypeOf channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors(counter) Is System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials Then
                    CType(channelFactory.Endpoint.Behaviors(counter), System.ServiceModel.Description.ClientCredentials).ClientCertificate.Certificate = New X509Certificate2("localhost.cer")
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next

        End If

        channelFactory.Open()
        Dim channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel()
        channel.Open()
```

Now the problem is once we try to establish a connection, we get "HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'"

We tried to change the:

httpsBinding.AuthenticationScheme

but no use.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try configuring IIS Client Certificate Mapping? 
Take a look at this article  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authentication/iisclientcertificatemappingauthentication